# How to do fallback for browser-specific css expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you specify browser-specific fallbacks for css properties in jquery?

E.g. I want to do the equivalent of

```
h1 {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, black);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white, black);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, white, black);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, white, black);
}
```

- `$('h1').css({'background-image': x, 'background-image': y})` -- js syntax of course will allow only one 'background-image' key.
- `$('h1').css('background-image', x).css('background-image', y)` -- jquery will overwrite the first value.
- `$('h1').css('background-image', x + ',' + y)` -- browser doesn't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the browser which prefix it wants by applying your CSS to an element and then reading back the value – `$('h1').css('background-image');`  You can then use the returned value to know what prefix to use when you set the `background-image` later.

Better yet, you could take advantage of jQuery's CSS hooks to normalize *all* calls to `.css`.    There's a great set of hooks [here](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks); you're probably interested in the [gradients hook](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/gradients.js).

Once the hook is installed, [it's as easy as:](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/JRznk/)

```
$(selector).css('background-image','linear-gradient(x,y,z)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to switch class, and declare the multiple values in CSS?

Comment: In this case the actual colors of the gradient values are programmatically determined and not constrained to a limited set of possible values, so that won't work for this problem.

Comment: Then write the styles on the fly.

Comment: Here's a good article on writing style elements dynamically. http://www.phpied.com/dynamic-script-and-style-elements-in-ie/